# ElementTree, how to find neighbor element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have XML file and it look like this:

```
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
<element>Element1</element>
<element_id>01</element_id>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<element>Element2</element>
<element_id>02</element_id>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<element>Element3</element>
<element_id>03</element_id>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

The value of `<element>` i take from form. Now i need to know `<element_id>` of this element. Please help me with it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath predicate to get a parent element where certain child element has certain value, for example `//parent[child='certain_value']`. Then from this point, you can simply return the other child element of the same parent, so the entire XPath will looks about like this `//parent[child='certain_value']/another_child`.

**Full working demo example specific to your case :**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

source = '''<ROWSET>
<ROW>
<element>Element1</element>
<element_id>01</element_id>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<element>Element2</element>
<element_id>02</element_id>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<element>Element3</element>
<element_id>03</element_id>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>'''
root = ET.fromstring(source)
target_element_value = 'Element2'
result = root.find('.//ROW[element="' + target_element_value + '"]/element_id')
print(result.text)
```

**output :**

```
02
```